# Getting a first element of the list within IO monad

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I'm trying to get the first element from the chain of IO monads (as far as I understand, I'm still learning Haskell):

```hs
getSomePath :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getSomePath path = do
    pomFile <- listDirectory path >>= filterM (\x -> return $ x == "pom.xml") >>= head
    -- here I'll add some more files 
    return [pomFile, someOtherFile]
```

The error appears when I'm trying to apply `head` function:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘IO FilePath’
      Expected type: [[Char]] -> IO FilePath
        Actual type: [IO FilePath] -> IO FilePath
    • In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘head’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        pomFile <- listDirectory path
                     >>= filterM (\ x -> return $ x == "pom.xml")
                     >>= head
```

I've also tried:

```
pomFile <- head (listDirectory path >>= filterM (\x -> return $ x == "pom.xml"))
```

with no result. How should I apply the head function to the `IO [a]` type so that it results with `IO a`? Is there a `head` equivalent for applying it to monads? I know I could just use [System.Directory.findFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.6.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:findFile) or something similar but I wanted to understand why my approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `head`, since the argument is here an `IO [a]`, not an `a`. You can however [**`fmap :: Function f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) on this, and thus obtain an `IO a`, or use the operator alias `<$>`.

That being said, using a `filterM` is here *not* necessary, you can just filter the list, and then take the head:

```
    pomFile <- (head . filter ("pom.xml" ==)) <$> listDirectory path
```

The above is however not *safe*. If the directory does contain a `"pom.xml"`, then it will simply return a `FilePath` (`String`) that is `"pom.xml"`. If it is not, it will raise an error that says you aim to retrieve the head of an empty list.

You thus likely can just work with:

```
    hasPomFile <- elem "pom.xml" <$> listDirectory path
```

here `hasPomFile` is thus a `Bool` that is `True` if the directory contains a `"pom.xml"`, and `False` otherwise.